Balance of deposit account using tidyverse / mutate
I am trying to write a script to get the balance of a deposit account with the following constraints:

There is an initial deposit (initial_investment)
There are yearly investments (planned_investments), which feed into the account (also from the first year)
The balance on the account generates an interest at the end of the year (rate)
The solution should work using tidyverse / mutate and be robust to cases where planned investments are zero (I would like to avoid using a loop)

Here is my solution so far:
library(tidyverse)

initial_investment <- 22950
rate <- 0.015 


overview_invests <- data.frame(id = 1:25, planned_investments = c(rep(1000, 20), rep(0,5))) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% mutate("balance" = initial_investment * (1 + rate)^id + sum(cumsum(planned_investments) * (1 + rate)^(id:1))) %>% ungroup() 

It works reasonly well but it cannot handle the cases where planned_investments are zero. Indeed, in such cases, the balance drops significantly (I assume that I am only getting the part of the sum from the initial_investment). It's probably quite simple to fix but I have tried multiple approaches unsuccessfully.
Thank you in advance for potential suggestions,

If you want to use the tidyverse, write a function to calculate the compound interests and use it in the pipe.
compound <- function(x, initial = 0, rate) {
  y <- numeric(length(x))
  y[1L] <- (initial + x[1L])
  for(i in seq_along(x)[-1L]) {
    y[i] <- (y[i - 1L] + x[i])*(1 + rate)
  }
  y
}

df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:25, planned_investments = c(rep(1000, 20), rep(0,5)))
initial_investment <- 22950
rate <- 0.015

df1 %>%
  mutate(balance = compound(planned_investments, initial_investment, rate))


Perfect, this is really what I was looking for! Since I want the interest to be applied from the start, I slightly modified the function: compound <- function(x, initial = 0, rate) { # Fonction pour calculer des intérêts composés à partir d'un investissement initial, d'injections annuelles et d'un taux de croissance
y <- numeric(length(x))
y[1L] <- (initial + x[1L])
y[1] <- (initial +  x[1])*(1 + rate)
for(i in 2:length(x)) {
y[i] <- (y[i - 1L] + x[i])*(1 + rate)
}
y
}

@JunkNatalia Glad it helped. And you don't have to repeat y[1L] <- (initial + x[1L]), the 2nd alone will do the job.

For this problem to handle the compounding of interest it is easier to perform this calculation with a loop.
planned_investments = c(rep(1000, 20), rep(0,5))
overview_invests<- initial_investment
for( i in 1:25) {
   overview_invests<- (overview_invests + planned_investments[i])*(1 + rate)^(1)
   print(overview_invests)
}

There is also the "FinCal" package to handle this.

Hello, Thank you for the quick feedback. Indeed, I already managed to do it with a loop, and I came up with a similar solution. I would like to use tidyverse/mutate since I may integrate it to a shiny app at a later stage. Do you think there is a way to make it work? Also I took a brief look at the FinCal package, and I cannot seem to find the relevant function unfortunately
